# Is there an easy way to make PVC from PVA?

Tags: home-experiment, safety, polymers

Say, I took Elmer's glue (or a similar Polyvinyl Acetate) and I inserted some Chlorine Tabs and warm it up while stirring.

Would the electronegative Chlorine turn some of it it into Polyvinyl Chloride (PVC)?

Would I get a Dioxin Compound too?

Would I get any other toxic Side-Product?

Comment: If it's a practical question, just **don't do it**. You won't get any PVC this way.

Comment: I want to tell you what the practical question is:
I mix together gelatin, casein, silicone and many others to try making bio-plastics from cheap home materials.
And some recipes also mention the use of PVA.
First of all: I do not want to accidently create toxic vapours, I was even afraid of mixing DMSO with EthylenAcetate.
Secondly: the PVA compound will always stay water solulable - could be nice to partly turn this compound into PVC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Choring Tablets have positivly charge cholrine atoms you want negative, so chlorine tablets will not work.  And no you won't get a dioxin compound unless you burn it, then you may ge some.  If you want to make PVC from PVA you can use Hydrochloric acid but you may not get a good yield.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
I was unable to vote you up, somebody has voted you down and I have no clue why he did.

Comment: I really don't think that HCl + PVA will give much PVC. It is always going to be far easier to make PVC from the monomer.